# Computation of fine using datetimepicker c#

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

```
conn.Open();
string sql = "Update tbl_return set DateReturned = @dreturn,Penalty = @penalty,DaysOverdue=@daysoverdue where ID=@id";
daysoverdue = (dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker3.Value).Days;

penalty = daysoverdue * fine;
txtfine.Text = penalty.ToString();
txtdoverdue.Text = daysoverdue.ToString();
MySqlCommand sda = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);

sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", time);
sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@penalty", penalty);
sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@daysoverdue", daysoverdue);
sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dreturn", datertrnd);
sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lblid.Text);

sda.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();

MessageBox.Show("Book has been Returned");
```

here is my code of computing fine of an overdue book. When I return the book before the due date, it results a negative number. I want it to be 0 when the book is returned after the due date. Pls help me.Thanks!

Comment: So is the problem with the computation, or with the SQL? Once you've worked that part out, you can eliminate the other side of it. What are the values of your variables?

Comment: int penalty;
            int fine = 20;
            int daysoverdue;

Comment: Please don't put the values in comments - edit your question. Ask yourself whether the SQL part is relevant, and remove it if it's not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
daysoverdue = (dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker3.Value).Days;
if(daysoverdue < 0)
   daysoverdue  = 0 

//in this case your penalty will be 0.
```

Comment: or shorter : `daysoverdue = Math.max(0, daysoverdue);`